# Why can't I create an EXTERNAL LANGUAGE for SQL Server 2019?

Tags: sql-server, administration, sql-server-2019

I am trying to understand what is wrong with my external language setup in SQL Server 2019.

I cannot execute any statements in my language 'Test1', which is designed to be an additional Python external language.  My goal here is to have multiple Python EXTERNAL LANGUAGES so I can have separate libraries for each, which would emulate virtual environments.

My failing script is:

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
@language =N'TEST1',
@script=N'
import pandas as pd
import sys
df = pd.DataFrame({"Version": sys.path + [ sys.executable ]})
OutputDataSet = df'
WITH RESULT SETS (([Version] nvarchar(256)));
```

This script executes just fine with the 'Python' language provided with the Machine Learning services for SQL Server 2019.

My (unhelpful) error message is:

> Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 87
> A 'TEST1' script error occurred during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT 0x80004004.
>
> Completion time: 2021-08-11T16:32:50.5880126-04:00

My setup is:

```
-- "Ensure that Machine Learning Services and Language Extensions are installed"
EXEC sp_configure 'external scripts enabled', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO

IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM sys.external_languages L WHERE L.language = 'TEST1')
BEGIN
    DROP EXTERNAL LANGUAGE TEST1
END
GO

-- From: https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-language-extensions/releases/tag/Python-v1.1.0
CREATE EXTERNAL LANGUAGE TEST1 
FROM (CONTENT = N'C:\LanguageExtensions\python-lang-extension-windows-release.zip', FILE_NAME = 'pythonextension.dll');
GO
```

Error logs at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ExtensibilityLog say:

> 2021-08-11 16:32:50.349   Start process exthost.exe successfully!
>
> 2021-08-11 16:32:50.581   Cleaning up the context for session id {9D7958AD-7EC2-48B4-B7E2-0D48D35DA2B5}
> 2021-08-11 16:32:50.581   Failed to delete directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\ExtensibilityData\Appcontainer1\9D7958AD-7EC2-48B4-B7E2-0D48D35DA2B5 with HR 0x80070020.
>
> 2021-08-11 16:32:50.581   Failed to delete files in directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\ExtensibilityData\Appcontainer1\26635237-9710-4B29-9233-5E72D1AA8204\Trace with HR 0x80070020.
>
> 2021-08-11 16:32:50.581   Failed to delete directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\ExtensibilityData\Appcontainer1\26635237-9710-4B29-9233-5E72D1AA8204\Trace with HR 0x80070091.
>
> 2021-08-11 16:32:50.581   Failed to delete directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\ExtensibilityData\Appcontainer1\26635237-9710-4B29-9233-5E72D1AA8204\Packages with HR 0x80070091.
>
> 2021-08-11 16:32:50.581   Failed to delete directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\ExtensibilityData\Appcontainer1\FA7BEFC1-F529-43DB-B5D6-68F32EF94BB8 with HR 0x80070020.
>
> 2021-08-11 16:32:50.581   Failed to delete directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\ExtensibilityData\Appcontainer1\F401FD5A-8563-4361-BCBD-04570C1F6FA0 with HR 0x80070020.
>
> 2021-08-11 16:32:50.581   Failed to delete directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\ExtensibilityData\Appcontainer1\C83DDF61-F6E5-431B-9A2B-EC4EF545D506 with HR 0x80070020.
>
> 2021-08-11 16:32:50.581   Failed to delete directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\ExtensibilityData\Appcontainer1\685BE366-D4FE-4C91-83CC-DE1F04AC1FEB with HR 0x80070020.
>
> 2021-08-11 16:32:50.581   Failed to delete directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\ExtensibilityData\Appcontainer1\26635237-9710-4B29-9233-5E72D1AA8204 with HR 0x80070020.

Things I have tried:

- I BCP'ed out the external_language_file CONTENT varbinary to disk to confirm that it got the right file and it had the right content. If you want to try this, you also need to create a .fmt file to make sure there are no leading bytes.
- I turned off cleanup and set TRACE level to 4 in rlauncher.config for better error reporting
- I granted full control to "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES" and "MSSQLLaunchpad" to AppContainer0, 1, 2 under `C:\ProgramData\MSSQLSERVER\Temp-PY` and `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\ExtensibilityData`
- I put `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES` on the system PATH

Any ideas?  I feel like it should be simple to stand up another Python language.

Maybe the language version provided at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES` doesn't match what's expected per https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-language-extensions/releases/tag/Python-v1.1.0?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have CU3+ installed.
2. Make sure that the path ending in PYTHON_SERVICES is on the system PATH and is also the value of PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH.  This will obviously clobber other things if you have other pythons installed, so you may wish to use the ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES parameter for the CREATE EXTERNAL LANGUAGE command instead of setting these system wide.
3. I don't assume risk or liability for this solution. Use at your own risk.